# Is there a way to fetch SQL Database table in iOS app connected to Azure App Service using Easy tables

Tags: ios, azure-sql-database

I created an Azure App Service and connected SQL Database. I also created easy table todoitem and another with the same name as I gave in SQL database. As the todoitem table is created on easy tables, post and get methods are working fine from iOS swift app. When I access the other table from iOS app, it does not fetch data available in SQL database. It returns blank response.

Is there a way to fetch Azure SQL database table data and display it in iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following Microsoft Dev Blogs: [Getting Started with Azure Mobile Apps’ Easy Tables](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/getting-started-azure-mobile-apps-easy-tables/). The Azure Mobile App Service allows for backend integration with Azure SQL Database using Easy Tables with the [Azure Mobile Apps iOS SDK](https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-ios-client/) running on the client. Here is a quick tutorial where you deploy the Azure Mobile App Service along with a sample iOS app. The only part missing is the Easy Table config and the Azure SQL Database integration but the Dev Blog covers that part: [Create an iOS app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started)